# Solspace Calendar: Calendar name not showing in .ics file

Tags: solspace-calendar

In case anyone is not aware of this: if you are using Solspace Calendar and are providing a subscription link, if you use http:// for the link, then the browser sends the .ics to the calendar client as a static file. Calendar changes and new events will not sync.

If you build the link using webcal:// the browser will pass it to the user's calendar client as a 'live link' and then will sync events and changes at intervals the user specifies.

Problem: The generated .ics file does not include the calendar title and thus the calendar name in the user's client ends up being the ulr to the .ics file.

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar#Calendar_extensions there is a property "X-WR-CALNAME" used to name calendar… How do we make this work with Solspace Calendar?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to do this but to edit the addon files yourself. You could try around line 4028 of `mod.calendar.php`, close to where you see:

`$E->setProperty('summary', $title);`

adding another line that looks like:

`$E->setProperty('X-WR-CALNAME', $title);`

That should in theory add the line you are looking for.

According to that article anything starting with an 'X-' is a non-standard, and being thus I am hesitant to add this as default as people use Calendar in so many different environments and icalendar file reading implementations are fickle enough as it is.

I have added a feature request to our queue to have some way in icalendar output to add custom attributes via parameters to the tag so in some future version this might be more easily doable.