# How do you Subscribe to a Calendar generated by Solspace Calendar

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

Maybe I am missing something as I am surprised this has not been more documented, but how do you "subscribe" to a calendar feed generated by Solspace Calendar?

My expected result would be that after adding a calendar by URL in Google Calendar, any changes I make to the calendar's events in EE would be reflected in Google Calendar.

The URLs I have tried (as per [this question](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/q/19921/3120)) are:

- `http://mydomain.com/events/icalendar-template`
- `webcal://mydomain.com/events/icalendar-template`

where /events/icalendar-template looks like this `{exp:calendar:icalendar}{/exp:calendar:icalendar}` and spits out the .ics file on direct visit via http://

On adding the calendar in Google Calendar, the events are correctly pulled through initially, but then don't update when I make changes in the EE.

I have also tried using a query string for the URL (as per [this thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/ixQnzHmWDSk)) just in case the problem was Google Calendar's but that hasn't fixed it.

EE version: 2.9.0, SC version: 1.8.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frustratingly, having tested this now also in OS X Calendar, the syncing seems to be working fine (I set the refresh rate to every 5 minutes as a test). It seems then like this is just an issue with Google Calendar - either that it is not syncing or is syncing very rarely.

Looks like I'll be spending a bit of time having a look through [this thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/ixQnzHmWDSk)!

So in summary, it seems like the above URLs (`http://mydomain.com/events/icalendar-template` and `webcal://mydomain.com/events/icalendar-template`) *do* work to subscribe to a calendar generated by Solspace Calendar with the above template `{exp:calendar:icalendar}{/exp:calendar:icalendar}` code. I should not that I have not thoroughly tested or explored the difference between the two protocols.